# Vulnerability / exploit MSDT (CVE-2022-30190) | Is renaming the registry key "ms-msdt" enough for the workaround?

Tags: windows, exploit

Microsoft publishes a workaround for the msdt exploit ([Guidance for CVE-2022-30190 Microsoft Support Diagnostic Tool Vulnerability](https://msrc-blog.microsoft.com/2022/05/30/guidance-for-cve-2022-30190-microsoft-support-diagnostic-tool-vulnerability/))

The suggested way is to delete the key `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ms-msdt` after backing it up:

> To back up the registry key, execute the command “reg export
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ms-msdt filename“ Execute the command “reg delete
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ms-msdt /f”.

I don't know how the registration of handlers like this work.

**Question:**
Wouldn't it be enough to rename the key like: `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ms-msdt__RenameBecause_cve-2022-30190` or would the handler still work regardless of the name?

**Why I'm asking this**: I would like to prevent registry backups on every machine, which may get lost.

---

**Edit**: I agree that its the best way to follow the microsoft recommendation. But with hundreds of pcs this way is difficult to implement reliably (not to mention that the registry backups have to be restored at some point)

Comment: Best to follow the Microsoft guidance on this, rather than try and come with an elaborate solution.

Comment: The article suggests that up to date Windows Defender (WIN 10 / 11) will mitigate the threat.

Comment: You are aware you would only have to keep a single backup of the key, right, since the keys to handle the URL handle would be identical across all your machines. With the key deleted you go from a situation where the URL handle can be used or change to not existing.  Of course the real solution is to use Microsoft Defender to detect and block the malicious behavior.

Comment: You don't need to backup the entire registry, you can store a reg file containing only the applicable keys if you so wish. Presumably this data would be identical across machines anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming is enough, as did the author of the article
[Mysterious “Follina” zero-day hole in Office – here’s what to do!](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2022/05/31/mysterious-follina-zero-day-hole-in-office-what-to-do/)

However, the author finished by deleting the key, as this mitigation
felt unfinished to him.

I would also suggest to delete the key, for a complete job.
You could export and keep the key before deleting it, as a better
method for backup.

Comment: His argument not to rename it is: 1) when somebody knows the new name it can be still used 2) he hasn't seen a usesfull use of this entry, so it may stay deleted. Very helpfull, thanks!